# GLS based on standard deviation condition

Tags: variance, generalized-least-squares

I want to perform a generalized least square model (GLS) with the gas data provided by the NIST/SEMATECH e-Handbook of Statistical Methods [1], where I want to predict pressure, based on temperature. Now, the linearized model for this relation has heteroskedasticity, so we want to addres that by performing a GLS.

And we want to perform the GLS model with this condition:

$$\sigma_i=\gamma_0+temp_{i}^{\gamma_1}$$

But I don´t know how to implement this using the `gls()` function in R.

Any help would be appreciated.

[1] https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section4/pmd452.htm

Comment: Did you see `varConstPower` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variance function `varConstPower` in the `nlme` library. See Pinheiro and Bates, page 212 for information about this variance function. The `varConstPower` variance function specifies the variance structure as

$$
\textrm{Var} (\epsilon_{i} ) = \sigma^2 (\delta_1 + |\textrm{temp}_i|^{\delta_2} )^2.
$$

In your `gls()` model, you will need to specify the variance structure by doing something like `weights = varConstPower(form = ~ temp)`.